# getting segmentation fault string s=s+"A";

Tags: c++, string

CASE 1
If i use
string s=s+"A"  i get segmentation fault

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    string s=s+"A";
    return 0;
}
```

CASE 2
but if i use
string s;
s=s+"A"   it works fine

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    string s;
    s=s+"A";
    return 0;
}
```

what is the reason of segmentation fault in case 1.
Also had it been any other datatype like int it works fine.

Comment: what do you think s holds at the first case?

Comment: `s` is uninitialized at `s+"A"`. `std::string` initializes itself to an empty string by default, but you suppress that by providing (or trying to provide) an initial value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

string s hasn't been initialized here yet:

```
string s=s+"A";
```

This is why you are getting a segmentation fault.

In the second case:

```
string s; // default value ""
s = s+ "A"; // you are getting "" + "A"
```

Comment: this works fine for int as they are initialized to 0 so i thought string s will be initialised to empty string

Comment: @Riya If you mean `int x = x + 1;` then no, it does not work. It is undefined behavior and if you see the result you expected, it is a coincidence. It might look like it works, because it probably doesn't crash, but it is actually worse.

Comment: @Riya: No, `int` variables are not initialised to `0`! (To be more accurate: `static` and global `int ` variables are initialised to `0`; local variables are not.)